# htaccess versioning, check if file exists in multiple places

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, versioning

Thanks in advance for your help!

So I have the following .htaccess code.
It seems to work.  However, it has to be the most bloated inefficient piece of work in existence.  There just HAS to be a better way to accomplish this.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html site-down.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(htm|html|php|jpg|jpeg|txt|png|gif|js|css)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1/ [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/v1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ v1/$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}index\.php -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ %0index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}index\.html -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ %0index.html [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}site-down\.php -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ %0site-down.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}(index\.php|index\.html|site-down\.php) !-f
RewriteRule ^.*$ controller.php [QSA,L]
```

This is what I am trying to accomplish.

1. Rewrite all requests to non-www
2. Check if file exists as requested.  If not,
3. Check if file exists in folder v1/+appended request, If not,
4. Check if an index file exists in folder v1/+appended request, If not,
5. Redirect to controller.php

As the htaccess file is used every single request I really need to get this a bit more logical/efficient.  The reason I added the index file chunk in the middle is that it wasn't checking if an index file existed when checking to redirect to controller.php.

Any ideas?  Thanks!